# Does argument parser in python has options like -continue or -single

Tags: python, python-2.7

Do we have any options in argument parser for continuing the execution from that respective position till the end of the code, on providing a command-line argument?

I have a script. When I execute with `script.py -f_2` it does execute only `function_2`. But I want to execute all the subsequent functions `function_3` & `function_4` as well till the end. How can I achieve this?

This script also read's and writes content from a file called sample_update.in using config parser.

```
import sys
import os
import math
import alert
import ConfigParser
import argparse
from alert import alert_user

configParser = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
configParser.add_section('Input')
configParser.add_section('Output')
configParser.read('sample_updated.ini')


def function_1(a, b):
    c = a + b
    # write to ini file
    print "input_1 of function_1: ", a
    print "input_2 of function_1: ", b
    print "output of function_1: ", c
    configParser.set('Input', 'function_1_1', str(a))
    configParser.set('Input', 'function_1_2', str(b))
    configParser.set('Output', 'function_1', str(c))
    return c

def function_2(c, b):
    d = c * b
    # write to ini file
    print "input_1 of function_2: ", c
    print "input_2 of function_2: ", b
    print "output of function_2: ", d

    configParser.set('Output', 'function_2', str(d))
    return d

def function_3(d, c):
    e = d / c
    # write to ini file
    print "input_1 of function_3: ", d
    print "input_2 of function_3: ", c
    print "output of function_3: ", e

    configParser.set('Output', 'function_3', str(e))
    return e

def function_4(d, e):
    f = d - e
    # write to ini file
    print "input_1 of function_4: ", d
    print "input_2 of function_4: ", e
    print "output of function_4: ", f

    configParser.set('Output', 'function_4', str(f))
    return f

if __name__ == '__main__':

    a = input("value of a: ")

    b = input("value of b: ")

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    # create argument parser

    parser.add_argument('-f_2', action='store_true', default=None, dest='function_2', help="execute from function_2")

    parser.add_argument('-f_3', action='store_true', default=None, dest='function_3', help="execution starts from function_3")

    parser.add_argument('-f_4', action='store_true', default=None, dest='function_4', help="execution starts from function_4")

    cmd_arguments = parser.parse_args()

    # print selected functions

    if cmd_arguments.function_2:
        function_2(configParser.getint('Output', 'function_1'), b)

    if cmd_arguments.function_3:
        function_3(configParser.getint('Output', 'function_2'), 

    if cmd_arguments.function_4:
        function_4(configParser.getint('Output', 'function_2'), configParser.getint('Output', 'function_3'))

    if not len(sys.argv) > 1:
        # store function outputs
        function_1(a, b)
        function_2(configParser.getint('Output', 'function_1'), b)
        function_3(configParser.getint('Output', 'function_2'), configParser.getint('Output', 'function_1'))
        function_4(configParser.getint('Output', 'function_2'), configParser.getint('Output', 'function_3'))

    with open('sample_updated.ini', 'w') as configfile:
        configParser.write(configfile)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no explicit function in `ConfigParser`.  You need to code that yourself.  To keep going in your case you should try:

```
if cmd_arguments.function_2:
    function_2(configParser.getint('Output', 'function_1'), b)

if cmd_arguments.function_2 or cmd_arguments.function_3:
    function_3(configParser.getint('Output', 'function_2'), 

if cmd_arguments.function_2 or cmd_arguments.function_3 or \
       cmd_arguments.function_4:
    function_4(configParser.getint('Output', 'function_2'),
```

Comment: thanks for the swift reply. Seems this works for sequential execution. But when i wanted to run only function_2 this might not support . Also, as we have only 4 functions this could be fine. But when i have around 15 functions to execute, this may not look good to put 14 or-conditions.

Comment: This is correct.  Bottom line, this is not a ConfigParser problem.  This is the domain of your program logic.

Comment: this is a simple script i am working to get the functionality. My actual script to which i would be appending this has around 23 functions to bring under this approach

Comment: Then you will need more complex logic to determine what you want to do.  But again, this is not the job of `ConfigParser`.  You will need to decide how to encode you intentions into a command line.

Comment: does arg parser also not have this kind of option? Can you suggest me how can i get it on my above script.

Comment: None of the command line argument tools have a such a feature.  They are designed to parse the command not write your program.